# What is the purpose of the "-1" in this code?

Tags: solidity

This is actually my own, contrived code, but it is based on what I am learning. In a video about creating arrays, he added a "-1" at the end of the line in which the ID number is pushed to the array.  He didn't explain, however, what the purpose of it was.  In my code, I added the "-1" for the array carListings, but left it out for the array truckListings.  Remix accepted the code and for the life of me, I cannot find any differences in the results.  It is important to note, however, that in the video, he used an address array, while I'm using integer arrays.  So, perhaps the "-1" has to do with addresses, but I still want to know either way, and there would still be the question of why my code was accepted with it.

```
// ---------- CARS ----------

uint public carID;
mapping(uint => Vehicle) cars;
uint[] public carListings;

function newCar(string _color, string _make, uint32 _year) public returns (uint ID) {
    carID ++;
    ID = carID;

    Vehicle storage car = cars[carID];
    car.color = _color;
    car.make = _make;
    car.year = _year;

    carListings.push(carID) -1;
}


// ---------- TRUCKS ----------

uint public truckID;
mapping(uint => Vehicle) trucks;
uint[] public truckListings;


function newTruck(string _color, string _make, uint32 _year) public returns (uint ID) {
    truckID ++;
    ID = truckID;

    Vehicle storage truck = trucks[truckID];
    truck.color = _color;
    truck.make = _make;
    truck.year = _year;

    truckListings.push(truckID);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does nothing, it's probably a mistake.

It would only matter if you were assigning that expression to a variable.

For example,

```
uint someVar = someArray.push(someOtherVar);
```

Will set someVar equal to the length of the array *after the push operation*. So if there were 4 items in the array, then you ran that code, afterwards the value of `someVar` would be `5`.

It's the equivalent of

```
someArray.push(someOtherVar);
uint someVar = someArray.length;
```

So with the `-1`, you're basically setting `someVar` equal to the array length - 1. Equivalent to:

```
someArray.push(someOtherVar);
uint someVar = someArray.length - 1;
```

*But*, in the code you provided, it isn't being assigned to anything (there is no `someVar`), so the result of the calculation (`length - 1`) is being immediately lost, meaning you're paying gas for a calculation you're never using.

Answer (score 2):

It's not doing anything in your implementation.

Since you're copying from another example, I will go out on a limb and infer what might be happening elsewhere.

`arrayName.push(value)` appends a value to a new row at the end of a dynamic *and returns the new list length*.

An empty array has `arrayName.length == 0`. After push, `arrayName.length == 1` and the value is is row 0 (start counting at 0).

So, `push(value)-1` gives the row number where the value was appended.

You could

`uint newRowNumber = arrayName.push(value) - 1` if there was a reason to.

Hope it helps.